# Data migrations of files object in Django - create a file data without having the file

Tags: python, django, data-migration

I'm having trouble in data migrating tables that contains FieldFile object. The problem here is that **I don't have the files yet**. I use a special method to create `ObjectFile`.

```
def create_object_file(file):
    return = ObjectFile.objects.create(
            name=name,
            content_type=file.content_type,
            extension=extension,
            uploaded_by=object_user,
            md5sum=file.md5sum,
            file=''
        )
```

File is a FieldFile. I need to register it without a file since I don't have the files yet.

I've tried to import a FieldFile from `django.db.models` thinking of instanciate it in order to attribute it to `file`. But it misses `chunks` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that one solution would have been using raw sql to populate new database.

So, this solution is not a real solution to the problem: how to migrate data file without files?

I managed to have some of the files I have to work on and I did what I had to, which is quite simple:

```
from django.core.files import File


def create_source_file(file, object_file):
    media = os.path.join(SOURCE_FILES, file.path)
    if not os.path.exists(media):
        return

    of = ObjectFile(
        name=name,
        content_type=file.file_type,
        extension=extension.lower(),
        md5sum=file.md5sum,
    )
    with open(media, 'rb') as m:
        of.file.save(file.name.lower(), File(m))
        of.save()
```